# Broadcast not delivered when App is not in the foreground/recent list

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Following is what happens:

- I have registered a network state change listener.
- When the control comes into it on network state change, I create an Alarm for 5 minutes later, to show a notification:

  ```
  Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
  alarmIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MODE, MODE);

  alarmIntent.setAction(NotificationReceiver.INTENT_ACTION);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + delay, pendingIntent);
  ```

here `delay` = 5000

- Then in NotificationReceiver, I show a notification
- I have defined the notification receiver in manifest like this: https://gist.github.com/Sheikh-Aman/ee40ec35c52ed9d66d6d
  (it wasn't appearing here don't know why)

Now when the network state changes, I do get a notification and I am able to set the Alarm.
When the alarm goes off, I don't receive the control in `onReceive` of `NotificationReceiver` most of the times, mainly when the app is not in the foreground and not in the recent task list.

Any idea why that would be happening or what am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:** I am able to reproduce it on a Nexus 5, running 5.x
This is how it is reproduced:

- Install the app
- Don't open it
- Change network state and receive no notification

Is it because the app has to be started at least once for it's alarms and broadcast receivers to work?

**FINAL UPDATE:** : Turns out that unless the app is started at least once after install, it remains in the `Stopped` state, which is equivalent to Force Closing an app from settings, and in this state, no broadcasts are delivered. This means I hit a platform limitation in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I saw you code. there are some changes in that. try to use this

```
// To get system time.
                Long systemTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
                alarmIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MODE, MODE);

                //set request code doffirent all the time  request=102
                // Alarm is delayed after the delay of 5 sec
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 102, alarmIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, systemTime + 5*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Isn't 5*60*1000 5 minutes delay and not 5 seconds? And alarm flag set to be 0 is the main difference here I guess. Also, you mean to say the request code must be different all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that unless the app is started at least once after install, it remains in the `Stopped` state, which is equivalent to Force Closing an app from settings, and in this state, no broadcasts are delivered. This means I hit a platform limitation in this case.